# Sitecore 8: The automation state for contact 46905fd6-25ee-4b91-a968-80cc29943e2f and plan 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 has not been found

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-ecm

I'm getting the following error message on Sitecore logs in one of our production environment.

```
MessageTaskRunner worker thread 3 06:40:35 ERROR EmailCampaign: Message sending error: Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Exceptions.EmailCampaignException: The automation state for contact 46905fd6-25ee-4b91-a968-80cc29943e2f and plan 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 has not been found.
   at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Analytics.AutomationStatesManager.EnrollOrUpdateContact(Guid contactId, Guid planId, String stateName, EcmCustomValues customValues, String[] validStates)
   at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Dispatch.DispatchManager.EnrollOrUpdateContact(Guid contactId, DispatchQueueItem dispatchQueueItem, Guid planId, String stateName, EcmCustomValues customValues)
   at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Dispatch.DispatchTask.OnSendToNextRecipient()
ManagedPoolThread #2 06:40:35 INFO  EmailCampaign: Dispatch Message (Unsubscribe Notification): Finished
ManagedPoolThread #2 06:40:35 INFO  Job ended: Sending message (C354709A5AEC45AD939190E246A3CEA4) (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #16 06:40:35 ERROR Could not update index entry. Action: 'Saved', Item: '{7356F179-B8D2-4091-AC17-D65F02E4416D}'
Exception: System.IO.IOException
Message: read past EOF
Source: Lucene.Net
   at Lucene.Net.Store.BufferedIndexInput.Refill()
   at Lucene.Net.Store.BufferedIndexInput.ReadByte()
   at Lucene.Net.Store.ChecksumIndexInput.ReadByte()
   at Lucene.Net.Store.IndexInput.ReadInt()
   at Lucene.Net.Index.SegmentInfos.Read(Directory directory, String segmentFileName)
   at Lucene.Net.Index.IndexFileDeleter..ctor(Directory directory, IndexDeletionPolicy policy, SegmentInfos segmentInfos, StreamWriter infoStream, DocumentsWriter docWriter, HashSet`1 synced)
   at Lucene.Net.Index.DirectoryReader.DoCommit(IDictionary`2 commitUserData)
   at Lucene.Net.Index.IndexReader.Commit(IDictionary`2 commitUserData)
   at Lucene.Net.Index.IndexReader.Commit()
   at Lucene.Net.Index.IndexReader.DecRef()
   at Lucene.Net.Index.IndexReader.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler.DeleteItem(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler.UpdateItem(Item item)
   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.IndexingProvider.UpdateIndexPhaseOne(HistoryEntry entry, Database database)
```

I have rebuild the Sitecore analytics database also.
But still I'm getting this error.

I tried submitting forms on our site, and it is working fine. I'm getting the subscription mails and the subscription notifications.

Thanks.

Comment: Does not look like your message engagement plan has been set see plan 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000. Can you check that?